# Using Microsoft Graph to pull in calendar events via RESTful is slow at some times of the day

Tags: java

I am using the Java Microsoft Graph API to pull in calendar events for a project.  I have to process a fairly large amount of calendar events (more than 50,000).

I'm invoking it using the following construction:

```
String urlString = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/" + calendarId + "/events?$select=subject,organizer,attendees,start,end,location&$filter=start/dateTime%20ge%20'" + trailingTwoYears + "'&count=true&$orderby=start/dateTime&$skip=" + SKIP + "&$top=50";
```

I have the following maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>adal4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
    <artifactId>oauth2-oidc-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>5.24.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Everything works great, except that I have noticed when I run it early in the morning, around 8AM Eastern Time,  it processes roughly 30 records/s. But by the afternoon, the speed of processing falls to about 5 records/s.  I have tried various values for the 'top' parameter, anything from 10 records per batch,  to 1000 records per batch,  it doesn't seem to affect the speed by much.  Not sure why it becomes so slow.  I may just need to schedule this cron job to run early in the morning to achieve fastest speed..

Comment: Have you check your network speed / capabilities around that time period? We noticed a similar behaviour at work and the reason behind it was another heavy-duty process running on the network around the same time.

Comment: this does not appear to be the case-- i have tried running it from another network location, and the rates are very similar across different locations, which indicates the problem may actually reside on the microsoft side.  the pattern i'm seeing is early in the morning and late in the evening, the speed is faster and during the day it becomes very slow.